# Find all of the private packages you have published to GitHub Packages

Tags: github-api

What's the API call to list all the published packages on GitHub?

I'm looking at GitHub API v4 GraphQL documentation but, since I don't know anything about GraphQL, I can't make sense of it.

At https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/deleting-a-package#deleting-a-version-of-a-private-package I found

> To find all of the private packages you have published to GitHub
>   Packages, along with the version IDs for the packages, you can use the
>   registryPackagesForQuery connection. You will need a token with the
>   read:packages and repo scopes. For more information, see
>   "registryPackagesForQuery" in the GitHub Developer documentation.

But after that I'm basically lost.

Answer (score 3):

Here a cURL command to use the `registryPackagesForQuery` function:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
-H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" \
-d '{"query":"{ user(login: \"OWNER\") { registryPackagesForQuery(first: 10, query:\"is:private\") { totalCount nodes { nameWithOwner versions(first: 10) { nodes { id version } } } } }}"}' \
https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Replace `OWNER` by your git login, and `TOKEN` by your personal token.

Comment: Adding this here for others who may find this later - if you want to find the same, for an organization, run this instead:
`curl -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
-H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" \
-d '{"query":"{ organization(login: \"OWNER\") { registryPackagesForQuery(first: 10, query:\"is:private\") { totalCount nodes { nameWithOwner versions(first: 10) { nodes { id version } } } } }}"}' \
https://api.github.com/graphql`